# Can we create a subsection of the References Cited section with different reference numbering?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I need to add some more publications. I do not want to change the previous reference numbers, so I need to create new citations with difference reference numbering like [p1], [p2], etc. Can LaTeX do that?

Comment: How exactly are you citing and managing references? Could you please post a Minimum Working Example which shows how you are doing this? There are several different systems for doing this in TeX and the best solution depends very much on which you are using. For example, cslstr's answer will work if you are using `biblatex` with `bibtex` or `biber` but not if you are using standard `bibtex` or LaTeX's standard `bibliography` environment. Moreover, I'm guessing from your comment that you 'do not want to change the previous reference numbers' that you are *not* using `biblatex` or `bibtex`.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{references} %references is the BibTex file that I store all the references. so this is bibliography environment? What do I do then?

Comment: No. You're using `bibtex`. But then I'm not sure what you mean about not wanting to change the previous reference numbers. If you use `bibtex` why is this a problem?

Comment: Thanks, I made it work. But I want to use siam style instead of ieee style. However, it says the bibliography style 'siam' could not be found. Do you know how to make siam style work?

Comment: It doesn't appear the `biblatex` has a standard style for SIAM.  Do you have a reference for how it should look?  You could have a look at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) to create one yourself, or modify an existing style that is close to what you need.

Comment: I made it work already. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I have recently done this type of thing to add a subset of references, namely those that were self-publications.  These were prefixed so that they stood out.

`biblatex` is the key to the method I used.  You can use the `keywords=` attribute in your bibfile to identify particular entries, then use the keyword to filter the references when you list your bibliographies in the end of the document.

A working example is below.  Remember that you need LaTeX -> BibTeX -> LaTeX -> LaTeX to compile.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} % Used only to create the bibfile
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
        @article{greenwade93,
                author  = "George D. Greenwade",
                title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
                year    = "1993",
                journal = "TUGBoat",
                volume  = "14",
                number  = "3",
                pages   = "342--351"
        }
        @book{goossens93,
                author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
                title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
                year      = "1993",
                publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
                address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
        }
        @article{blackholes,
                author="My Self",
                title="Black Holes and Their Relation to Hiding Eggs",
                journal="Theoretical Easter Physics",
                publisher="Eggs Ltd.",
                year="2010",
                note="(to appear)",
                keywords="self"
        }
\end{filecontents*}
% NOTE: Last entry has a _keywords="self"_ attribute.  This keyword is used to 
%       sort out specific entries when the bibliographies are made

% biblatex is used with a few of my preferred options 
% -- style = ieee  gives [1] format
% -- backend = bibtex - can also use 'biber'
% -- sorting = ynt  sorts all entries in each bibliography by Year, Name, then Title
% -- defernumbers = true  required to get the resetnumbers=true option to work down below
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,sorting=ynt,defernumbers=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % Peculiar to biblatex

\begin{document}

This document references \cite{greenwade93}, and my own publication 
(\cite{blackholes}).  And I also used \cite{goossens93}.

% References split out into self publications and regular references
% This makes use of biblatex (still needs a _bibtex_ run to finalize)
\section{Publications and References}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, notkeyword=self, title={References}, resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, keyword=self, title={Publications}, resetnumbers=true, prefixnumbers={P}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I made it work. Do you know how to use siam style instead of ieee style? I changed style=ieee to siam, but it does not recognize siam style.