# Beamer: custom order of references

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I usually include references in my beamer-presentation like this:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle<presentation>{References}    
    \bibliographystyle{acm}
    \nocite{A}
    \nocite{B}
    \nocite{C}
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \bibliography{../sources}
\end{frame}
```

However, for a talk I am going to give, I would prefer to have the two most important papers at the beginning (first references slide), followed by a second slide with the rest of the references. How can I achieve this WITHOUT writing everything myself using bibtex?

Comment: You might try with `biblatex`, using keywords to differentiate between "important" and others. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164314/47522)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cslstr's comment pointed me in the right direction. For future reference, here is a complete (minimal) answer:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{sources.bib} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
    \nocite{A}
    \nocite{B}
    \nocite{C}
    \nocite{D}
    \nocite{E}
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[triangle]
    \printbibliography[keyword=main]
    \bigskip
    \printbibliography[notkeyword=main]
\end{frame}
```

This will first list the references out of {A,B,C,D,E} that have the keyword "main"; the rest is listed after some free vertical space.