# references as a subsection

Tags: bibliographies, books

I am working with a `\documentclass{book}` document. It contains several chapters which have very few references, so that I choose to provide them as `\foonote`(s).
But I have a single chapter with many references. I am wondering if I can construct a subsection (or section), in the end of the chapter, which containst the references of this one.
E.g.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
 \usepackage{caption}

 \frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true}

 \usepackage{paralist}

 \usepackage{geometry}

 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table des mati\`eres}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=red,
   urlcolor=blue,
   pdftitle={Dossier de Candidature},
   pdfauthor={Dimitrios S. Anagnostou}]{hyperref}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter-pages}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyfoot[L]{\hyperref[ToC-first-page]{Jump to Contents}}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \clearpage
  \phantomsection% Place hyperlink marker
  \label{ToC-first-page}% Set \label for hyperlink
  \oldtableofcontents
}
\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \clearpage
  \oldmainmatter
  \pagestyle{mainmatter-pages}%
}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

 \usepackage{pdfpages}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5cm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21.0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}

\newcommand{\M}{{\it Mathematica}}
\providecommand\Matlab{\textsc{Matlab}}

\newcommand{\FIG}[2]
{
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
\centering{\includegraphics[]{#1}}
\caption{\label{#1}\small{#2}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
}

\parindent0pt  \parskip10pt

    \begin{document}

    \title{DOSSIER DE CANDIDATURE}
    \author{Dimitrios Papas\thanks{vbkvbkvbdkvbd}}

    \affil{
    Université\ldots}

    \date{\begin{center}
    Docteur en Mécanique
    \end{center}}

    \maketitle \thispagestyle{empty}

    \frontmatter  

    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter  

    \chapter{First}

    \section{First section}

    \section{Expérience professionnelle}

    \begin{description}

    \item Depuis 09/2016
    \begin{compactitem}
    \item foo
    \begin{compactitem}
    \item foo
    \end{compactitem}
    \end{compactitem}

    \end{description}

    \chapter{Second}
    \section{First}
    \section{Second}
    \subsection{Références bibliographiques}


    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{latexcompanion} 
    Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
    \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
    Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

    \bibitem{einstein} 
    Albert Einstein. 
    \textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
    [\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
    Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.

    \bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
    Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
    \\\texttt{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
    \end{thebibliography}

    \end{document}
```

How can I include the elements of bibliography inside the subsection called "Références bibliographiques"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164294/can-we-create-a-subsection-of-the-references-cited-section-with-different-refere?rq=1  Exactly how do you want this to work?